# Can the below query be rebuilt using setbased rather than iterative logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am preparing one SSRS report and i have only select access in the table.
I have built the query to get the data.But since i am using table variables, and not getting the desired output in report.

Here is my table structure:

This table stores each job run data with below columns:

```
jobname  
instance_id--ever increasing unique number for each run  
starttime   
endtime    
status
```

I want to show in my report all above columns and I wrote the query like below.

since I want to show latest run irrespective of success or failure, I need to get max(instance_id) into one table and from that base table I am passing all in loop.
I am getting max instance_id along with row number  for looping purposes

```
 create table   ##table      
(      
fqjn varchar(1000),       
maxi int,        
rownum int      
)     

create table ##tb       
(jobname varchar(max),         
[status] varchar(100),         
duration int         
)        
insert into ##table      
select  jobname,max(instance_id) as maxi,row_number() over (order by jobname desc) as rownum from [dbo].[vw_job_hist]
where grp_data_id in (select grp_Data_id from [dbo].[vw_job_data] where grp_name='pcp')
group by jobname   

--now loop through table passing instance_id as parameter     
declare @rownum int      
select top 1 @rownum=rownum from ##table order by rownum         

while @rownum is not null       
begin       

insert into ##tb       
select jh.jobname,"job status"=    
case jh.completion_status      
when 0 then 'Success'      
else 'Failed'      
end,       
"duration"=datediff(minute,jh.started_time,jh.end_time)      
from [dbo].[vw_job_] jh      
where jh.instance_id in (select maxi from ##table where rownum=@rownum)  

set @rownum=(select top 1 rownum from ##table where rownum>@rownum          
order by rownum      

end     

select * from ##tb      
drop table ##tb      
drop table ##table
```

I am not getting the desired output in SSRS ,i know if i create the above query as stored proc,i will get the desired results.but this is third party database and we wont get access.

ask:

- Can the above query logic be built in single query with out loop/cursor
- I tried using recursive cte ,but no further progress

any help/pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH OrderedJobInfo AS (
    SELECT  jobname, completion_status, started_time, end_time, instance_id
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY jobname ORDER BY instance_id DESC) AS rownum
    FROM    [dbo].[vw_job_hist]
    WHERE   grp_data_id IN (SELECT grp_Data_id FROM [dbo].[vw_job_data] WHERE grp_name='pcp')
)
SELECT  o.jobname, o.instance_id
        , [job status] = CASE o.completion_status WHEN 0 THEN 'Success' ELSE 'Failed' END
        , [duration] = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.started_time, o.end_time)  
FROM    OrderedJobInfo o
WHERE   o.rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin,This is amazing,this worked.Still trying to understand how this works.can you please explain how this works

Comment: @TheGameiswar Glad this was helpful.  The "WITH" clause is a CTE, which behaves a little like a view or temp table that you can use in the current query, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx .  In the CTE, I am using ROW_NUMBER function to number the jobs with most recent first.  The PARTITION BY clause re-starts the count every time the "jobname" changes.  Then, in the main query, I just have to pull the records that have a 1 in their "rownum."  It's a very common pattern, so I hope it's useful to you in the future.